# OneLogin User Provisioning with SCIM 2.0

Tags: provisioning, onelogin, scim, scim2

I am creating a web application compliant with SCIM 2.0. I can create and update users using provisioning, but deleting users always fails.

So, I tried a number of things to resolve my issue, and I found that the "SCIM Provisioner with SAML (Core Schema)" application only accepts the HTTP **200** (Success) status code to indicate a successful delete.

My application returns a **204** (No Content) status code for the DELETE method, in accordance with the [RFC 7644 (SCIM Protocol)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.6) (emphasis mine):

> In response to a successful DELETE, the server **SHALL** return a
> successful HTTP status code **204** (No Content).

Since the [SCIM developer documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/scim) states that OneLogin *"[...] supports SCIM 1.1 and SCIM 2.0"*, is the current approach correct? Should I change my status code to 200, and risk running into issues with providers that do correctly implement the SCIM 2.0 protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUSPEND on delete instead of DELETE on delete in OneLogin SCIM App Provisioning Menu.